# Golang unused type (but it's used)

Tags: go, goland

The following struct gives the warning:

> Unused type 'Device_Type_Struct

```
type Device_Type_Struct struct {
    Id              string              `json:"_id"`
    BrandName       string              `json:"brandName"`
    Category        string              `json:"category"`
    Firmware        string              `json:"firmware"`
    Label           string              `json:"label,omitempty"`
    Model           string              `json:"model"`
    Supported       bool                `json:"supported"`
    Type            string              `json:"type"`
    Platform        string              `json:"platform,omitempty"`
    OvrcPro         bool                `json:"ovrcPro"`
    OvrcHome        bool                `json:"ovrcHome"`
    LogTimeSeries   bool                `json:"logTimeSeries"`
    Attributes      Attributes_Struct   `json:"attributes"`
}
```

However, it is used:

```
var deviceType Device_Type_Struct
err = json.Unmarshal(buf, &deviceType)
if err == nil {
    println("Request unmarshalled")
} else {
    println("Error unmarshalling request to Device_Type_Struct")
}

insertedId, err := db.UpsertOne("devicetypes", deviceType)
if err != nil {
    println("Error upserting document")
    success = false
}
```

Is there any reason for this or is it just an IDE error?

Comment: Are these in the same package? What is issuing this warning?

Comment: The go toolchain doesn't produce warnings, some other tool is doing that. If you are using it, then it seems like an incorrect warning.

Comment: @Adrian they are both in the same file

Comment: Can you please give a screenshot of the error tooltip? Also, make sure you use 2018.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply an IDE error. After I restarted my laptop, GoLand no longer displayed any errors.